# Laravel Create Record and Use ID Value in Another Column

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I create a new record in my Fan model, at the same time that I create the new Fan record, I want to use the new ID value in another column. I'm trying to do this all at once and not have another method to go back and update the record.

```
$fan = Fan::create([
    'display_name' => $displayName,
    'bio' => $bio,
    'logo_url' => $logoUrl,
    'algolia_id' => 'fan_'??, // I want to replace ?? with this record's ID value.
]);
```

I've tried $fan, but doesn't work since that variable isn't created yet. I cannot use Auth because the ID isn't the Auth user's ID.

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to do this? Surely if the second field just contains the ID and a suffix / prefix you can do this outside of the database in each model using laravels `appends` functionality.

Comment: It's for Algolia really, I need to assign a unique ID for each record. Algolia will update my index when I create the new record, but I'm having trouble updating that record in the index after it has been created. So, I'd like it all done in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you can automatically do it, you should do it in 2 steps:

```
$fan = Fan::create([
    'display_name' => $displayName,
    'bio' => $bio,
    'logo_url' => $logoUrl
]);

$fan->algolia_id = 'fan_' + $fan->id;
$fan->save();
```

That said, it's not a great database design, you'd rather want to build the `algolia_id` field when you need to use it, since you'd store duplicated value (the `id` and the `algolia_id` are the same except for `fan_`).

Comment: Right, I want them done at the same time or the algolia_id will have to update later, which can cause issues. I guess I can assign an increment of the max ID already in the DB to a variable and use that since that will still equal the new ID.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, what if you insert a new value between the time you get the max ID and you create the new `Fan`? It wouldn't work. I'm afraid a two-step solution is the only possible one :/